# Is it possible to run application to IOS 6 device from XCode 4.2 with Snow Leopard?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I have snow leopard with XCode 4.2. Is it possible to run applications on IOS 6 device from it. As we can run applications to IOS 5.1 by copying few files as /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.1 (9B176)

Comment: You have to update your Mac and your xCode .

Answer (score 0):

The steps to use your updated iOS 6 device for development with Xcode 4.3.2 thus are:

Download Xcode 4.5 DP from the dev area of apple.com.

Install Xcode 4.5

Start up Xcode 4.3.2

Open up the devices section, choose your device for development, wait for the process of fetching information to finish and you are good to go.

Regards!

Comment: Thanks but I need this with XCOde 4.2